# GPU overheating before booting Windows

Tags: gpu, overheating

I have an ATI Radeon 5770. As soon as I start up the computer the GPU fans are on full blast, up until Windows finishes starting up. The fans stop as soon as the Windows login screen comes up.

What this means for me is that if I spend more than a few minutes tweaking BIOS settings, the GPU will overheat and the screen will go black.

What's causing this? I've updated to the latest ATI drivers.

Comment: The latest drivers to which you updated are for Windows and, obviously, aren't running before Windows starts up and loads them.

Comment: What would be the solution then? Is there a separate set of drivers I need to install?

Comment: It's not a driver problem. It could be a bad card; it could be a design flaw; it could be that some setting needs to be changed (physically or in software). AMD has a support community where you could ask about this: https://community.amd.com/community/support-forums

Comment: So I assume it did black out already, right? The fans could be unrelated, though.

Comment: Daniel, the screen blacks out after a few minutes if I don't get to the Windows login screen immediately. I assumed the fans going at full blast indicated the GPU doing a ton of work, seemingly for no reason. It gets super hot to the touch too.

Comment: That’s okay, just making sure. Some (old-ish) GPU coolers ran at full speed until the driver was running.

Comment: An answer was inappropriately deleted: the CPU (mentioned in the question) is probably overheating due to a poll loop set up by the boot loader.  GPU fans spin up when the computer is turned on (that's normal and unrelated to the main problem).  The question should be edited into two separate posts.